# Connect Go to Mongo Atlas and find documents

Tags: mongodb, go

I'm a newbie to `Go` and trying to connect my sample application to Mongo Atlas

I`ve create a cluster in Mongo Atlas which has the following information:

[image]

I'm trying to retrieve documents from the collection but it fails to find any:

- I'm able to connect to the DB, but when I run `.Find()` then I get an error of `document is nil`

When i run a specific query (for email) then it works.

When i run a general query (`context.TODO()`) then it is not working

What am I missing here?

```
    const connectionStr = "mongodb+srv://" + MONGO_USER + ":" + MONGO_PASSWORD + "@cluster0.3ymvqrs.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"

serverAPIOptions := options.ServerAPI(options.ServerAPIVersion1)
clientOptions := options.Client().
    ApplyURI(connectionStr).
    SetServerAPIOptions(serverAPIOptions)
ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
defer cancel()
client, err := mongo.Connect(ctx, clientOptions)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err, client)
}

// Select the database and collection
database := client.Database("sample_mflix")
commentsCollection := database.Collection("comments")

// Retrieve documents from the collection
// cursor, err := commentsCollection.Find(context.TODO(), nil) // not working
cursor, err := commentsCollection.Find(ctx, bson.M{"email": "roxanne_mckee@gameofthron.es"}) // working
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
defer cursor.Close(context.TODO())
```

Comment: The screenshot shows documents from the `sample_airbnb` database, and you're querying `sample_mflix`. We don't know if you really have documents in the database and collection you're querying based on the screenshot.

Comment: @icza correct, I've update the screenshot in my question above

Comment: You must not use `nil` as the filter document. That's why you got that error. Use an empty document such as `bson.M{}` or `bson.D{}` if you want to get all results.